# why redux-offline with react-native not send the POST request?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-offline

I have **delete_task** action that POST the task id to PHP file to delete the task , although the action I fired correctly and i see the effect in the console but the task not deleted, i tried many many times using GET OR POST OR JUST put the id statically in the URL but nothing changing,can anyone help me to solve the problem

**tasksAction.js**

```
export  const delete_task = id => ({
    type: DELETE_TASK,
    payload: {id},
    meta: {
        offline: {
            // the network action to execute:
            effect: { url: 'http://localhost/todos/remove.php', method: 'POST',body: {id} },
            // action to dispatch when effect succeeds:
            commit: { type: DELETE_SUCCESS, meta: { id } },
            // action to dispatch if network action fails permanently:
            rollback: { type: DELETE_FAILED, meta: { id } }
        }
    }
});
```

**store.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from 'redux';
import { offline } from '@redux-offline/redux-offline';
import offlineConfig from '@redux-offline/redux-offline/lib/defaults';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

import RootNavigator from "./config/routes";
import reducers from './reducers'


// store
const middleware = [];
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
    middleware.push(logger);
}
const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    undefined,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(...middleware),
        offline(offlineConfig)
    )
);

export default class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
            <RootNavigator />
            </Provider>

        )
    }
}
```

[image: Logger Result]

Answer (score 0):

In the offline object inside `prev state`, does it say `online: false`?

If it does, and you're developing in an Android emulator, Wifi is not available on the emulator if you are using below API level 25, so redux-offline thinks you have no connection and will not make the initial network request.

This occurred to me after testing redux-offline in an iOS simulator and everything worked.

Hope this helps.